# What is the archaic Canadian word for a chesterfield throwover?

Tags: canadian-english

So in a casual conversation with other Canadian writers, I asked the question because I was told by my parents that there was a specific word used by their parents for the throwover you place on the chesterfield.  I asked my parents and they said they forgot.  The writers I was talking with said that they knew of this word too but also forgot.

Perhaps someone here knows.  What is that word?  I have to assume that this word was used in the first half of the 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

***afghan***.  See [Afghan, (blanket) Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_(blanket)):

> An afghan is the knitted or crocheted wrap that everyone has seen
>   thrown over the back of a rocking chair or folded at the foot of
>   Grandmother's bed. Afghans are often given as gifts and may become
>   family heirlooms. Many people use an afghan as a throw on a chilly
>   day, as a bedspread, or as decoration for the back of a chair. An
>   afghan also makes a good three-season wrap, adding warmth without a
>   lot of weight.

It's not just a Canadian word and it is in use today, although *throw* may be more common.  See [Throws for a Chesterfield Sofa](http://www.mychesterfieldsofa.com/throws-for-a-chesterfield-sofa/).  I have never heard the term *throwover*.  (Native speaker of American English, mostly BosWash corridor.)

The word afghan, referring to a person of Afghanistan, dates to 1831, but the first use of the word to mean the woven blanket was in 1877.  I speculate that the word for the blanket fell out of favor with the increasing politicization of the situation in Afghanistan in the late 1970s, but I have not researched this point.

Comment: I know of the word "afghan" but that doesn't seem to be the word that was used.